# Query to return list of a particular element from object list in mongo -db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to get the list of a particular attribute from various objects in the list.

For example :- Suppose we have 5 objects(Let's say collection name is "a" here) in the database and each object has Telephone no(say) attribute with different values for every object.

I am trying to find all the Telephone nos using below query :-

**db.getCollection("a").find({object.Telephoneno});**

However I am not able to retrieve the list of Telephone nos.

Can anyone suggest what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use distinct to find all the unique telephone no.

Try the below query :

```
 db.getCollection("a").distinct("Telephoneno");
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked . I am now able to get the TN list.